# Reroute Audio to Bluetooth Speaker

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiosession

I am creating a Video & Audio capturing app. Every time I start to record, the music played in the bluetooth speaker plays in the phone's speaker. When I exit the app, the music comes back playing on the bluetooth speaker.

My first attempt to solve this is to provide the necessary options for the `audioSession`, like this:

```
try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, withOptions: [AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.MixWithOthers, AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.AllowBluetooth])
```

But that didn't work. So my second solution that I'm thinking is to reroute the music output again to the bluetooth speaker.

I researched on this and found this function: `audioSession.setOutputDataSource`

I don't really know the parameters to be passed there.

And I am not really sure if in the moment I started the video recording, the phone/or my code disables the bluetooth connection or it just reroutes the playback to the phone's speaker.

UPDATE: I coommented out this line: `// try audioSession.setMode(AVAudioSessionModeMoviePlayback)` and the music pauses a bit and plays again on the bluetooth speaker. But the problem here is that the captured video has no audio.

UPDATE 2: Would this question have a solution if I provide you with my code?

Comment: Are you trying to get it to play through bluetooth, or the default output which happens to be bluetooth. For example, do you want it to play through bluethooth no matter what, or only when the phone/tablet is hooked up with a different primary output (like AUX, or bluetooth)

Answer (score 0):

I'll go ahead and take a shot at answering the original question. From Apple
s documentation I go this:

```
func setOutputDataSource(_ dataSource: AVAudioSessionDataSourceDescription?)throws
```

> **Parameters** *dataSource*
>
> The data source for the audio session’s output.
>
> *outError* 
>   On input, a pointer to an error object. If an error occurs, the pointer is set to an NSError object that describes the
>   error. If you do not want error information, pass in nil. [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAudioSession/setOutputDataSource:error:)

This page should help you figure out what the AV Session data source description does/returns, but in summery it:

> You obtain data source descriptions from the shared AVAudioSession object or the AVAudioSessionPortDescription objects corresponding to its input and output ports. Only built-in microphone ports on certain devices support the location, orientation, and polar pattern properties; if a port does not support these features, the value of its dataSources property is nil. [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSessionDataSourceDescription_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVAudioSessionDataSourceDescription)

Are you trying to route music from your app to the speaker (is that the music playing?) or is the music coming from another app, and you would like a dual output?

For error checking you could make sure the speaker is still available, using something like the [output data source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAudioSession/outputDataSource). If it returns nill (null.) it means you are not able to switch between data-sources.

It's probably also worth noting the user must give you permission to record, however I doubt this is the problem as you seem to have already been recording at one point, just when it was playing through the phone, not the speaker

Comment: I would like to have the bluetooth speaker to be the default output if it's connected. Or if I can output the sound for both the phone's speaker and the bluetooth speaker, it would also be okay.

Comment: You won't be able to play through both speakers, the output redirection overrides the existing path. Did you have any luck with the setOutputDataSrouce? Does the arguments required make sense?

Comment: I dont really understand `setOutputDataSource`. I need a sample usage of that please.

Comment: My limited understanding would be that the first argument is your source (the sound you want to play) and the second would be that method, which would return the output path (such as the bluetooth speaker); unfortunately I don't have a license to use Xcode or Swift (thus my lack of confidence, on this subject) so I can't provide much of an example usage, I did look around online and didn't find much sadly :/